# Grep for pattern recursive and disable file

Tags: bash

On a shared host, I'd like to setup a cron which scans folders recursively for some base64 malware strings. Therefore, I've written the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo $0: usage: ./findone folder_to_start_with
    exit 1
fi

folder=$1

IFS=$'\n'
searchfiles=($(grep -r -F -n -f malware-strings.dat $folder))

for (( i=0; i<${#searchfiles[@]}; i++ ));
        do
                STR=$(echo ${searchfiles[i]} | awk -F':' '{print $1}')
                    if [ -z "$STR" ]; 
                        then true; 
                        else chmod 000 $STR;
                    fi            
        done

## Do something else like mail results etc.
printf '%s\n' "${searchfiles[@]}"
```

My locals test are doing what I expect. If a string pattern from "malware-string.dat" is found the file permission is changed to 000. Before scanning the production sites, I wanted to ask for a code review as I'm new to Bash and do not want to mess things up. Also, your judgement of disabling the file with `chmod` is enough would help, or if it is advisable to move the file outside of the www directory.

Comment: Why don't you delete it?

Comment: I guess you are using `chmod 000` (instead of `rm`) to allow later inspection. If that's the case, then I'd move the file to another directory: in some situations, files may be read even if they are `-r`.

Comment: You need to put any variable containing fileeor directory names in double quotes. Otherwise, names containing spaces, shell metacharacters etc will not work.

Comment: Your script will not work correctly on file names containing colons, either.

Comment: Hi triplee thanks for your reply means `else chmod 000 "$STR"` should do it?

Comment: Hi  Andrea Corbellini, correct the idea behind chmod was to inspect them later I will `mv` them to a save place. But I cannot think of a situation where one can read a file with permission 000. Can you give me a buzzword?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Heslacher got it thanks `You also should not append your revised code to the question. Posting improved code is an answering activity, not a questioning activity.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input checking is not very strict. Any argument could pass that check, even an empty string, but the script needs specifically a valid path to a folder. So why not check for that:

```
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo $0: usage: ./findone folder_to_start_with
    exit 1
fi
```

The `grep` command will output the matched lines, with the line number. But you don't need those, only the filename. And there could be multiple matches per file. It would be better to use the `-l` flag, and that way you won't need the `awk` at all, you will get only the file names, ready to use.

This condition is very awkward:

> ```
> if [ -z "$STR" ]; 
>     then true; 
>     else chmod 000 $STR;
> fi
> ```

Instead of an empty branch that does nothing, you could have flipped the condition by simply dropping the `-z`, and the unused branch with it, resulting in the simpler:

```
if [ "$STR" ]; 
    then chmod 000 $STR
fi
```

(In any case, when you rewrite the `grep` to use `-l`, this condition will not be needed, so this part will be simply gone.)

As you guessed, in addition to `chmod` it would be better to move the file out of the vulnerable directory, to a safer place. One reason is to make it less vulnerable, another is that these files buried deep within your web directories might go unnoticed easier. I'd also suggest adding email alerts after detecting such malware.

Answer (score 2):

- Bash idiom for looping over searchfiles is

  ```
  for file in $searchfiles; do
      process "$file"
  ```
- Invoking `awk` just to print a field looks like an overkill. Consider

  ```
  read -d : str rest <<< "$file"
  ```

Comment: The way he loops is safe for directories containing spaces, your suggestion is simple at the expense of safety sacrificed

Comment: What does `read -d : str rest <<< "$file"` do?